# How to select first letter of all items in a Python list?

Tags: python

I need to produce some code which loops through all of the elements in the list variable called 'list_1' and prints each element that begins with the letter 'p'.

```
list_1 = ['albania','portugal','pakistan','moldova','chile','brazil','paraguay','canada',
          'panama','indonesia','philippines','new zealand','palestine','papua new guinea']

for i in range(len(list_1)):
    if(left(i[0])=='p'):
        print i
```

This is the best I have managed but it errors ("NameError: name 'left' is not defined")

Comment: What do you expect `left` to mean?

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can directly iterate over the elements, so you don't need to calculate the size of the list.

```
 for element in list_1:
     if element[0] == 'p':
         print(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options. Either use `.startswith()` or you can use indexing. If you want case sensitivity, just remove `.lower()`

Method 1

```
list_1 = ['albania','portugal','pakistan','moldova','chile','brazil','paraguay','canada',
          'panama','indonesia','philippines','new zealand','palestine','papua new guinea']

list_2=[word for word in list_1 if word.lower().startswith('p')]
```

Method 2

```
list_1 = ['albania','portugal','pakistan','moldova','chile','brazil','paraguay','canada',
          'panama','indonesia','philippines','new zealand','palestine','papua new guinea']

list_2=[word for word in list_1 if word.lower()[0]=='p']
```

If you don't want list comprehension, you can do the following

```
for j in list_1:
    if j.startswith.lower('p'): #== or simply j.lower()[0]=='p':
        print(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in list_1:
    if i.startswith('p'): print(i) # works for empty strings too
```

and please no for i in range(len(list_1)), just for i in list_1

Answer (score 0):

Simply iterate over the list using for loop. Check if at 0 index(first letter) of i (i.e. the element in the list )'p' is present or not. If present, then print it.

Code:

```
list_1 = 
['albania','portugal','pakistan','moldova','chile','brazil','paraguay','canada',
      'panama','indonesia','philippines','new zealand','palestine','papua new guinea']

for i in list_1:
    if(i[0]=='p'):
        print(i)
```

Output:

```
portugal
pakistan
paraguay
panama
philippines
palestine
papua new guinea
```